# Why am I not getting the expected output?

Tags: python

I wrote the following simple Python script:

```
def add(x,y):
    print '%d + %d = ' % (x,y)
    return x+y

def subtract(x,y):
    print '%d - %d = ' % (x,y)
    return x-y

def multiply(x,y):
    print '%d x %d = ' % (x,y)
    return x*y

def divide(x,y):
    print '%d / %d = ' % (x,y)
    return x/y

x = 8
y = 4

add(x,y)
subtract(x,y)
multiply(x,y)
divide(x,y)
```

The issue is that I don't get the result of each operation, and the output looks as follows:

```
8 + 4 = 
8 - 4 = 
8 x 4 = 
8 / 4 =
```

What am I missing to make the result appear after the `=` sign?

Comment: `print(add(x,y))`? <--- print it out!

Comment: You are never doing anything with the return value?

Comment: If you type an expression into the interpreter in interactive mode, Python will auto-print its value, but that's just an interactive thing. `return` and `print` do nearly unrelated jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions only print the equation part. You never print the result of the Python expression. `return` is not the same thing as `print()`.

You may be confused with the behaviour of the Python interactive interpreter mode, where the result of *any* expression executed at the `>>>` prompt is *echoed* (unless it produced the special value `None`). Running a script does not do this, expressions are not automatically echoed this way. You need to explicitly print the result:

```
def add(x,y):
    result = x + y    
    print '%d + %d = %' % (x, y, result)
    return result
```

It is better design to not print inside such functions however. If you wanted to use the function and *not* print the equation and outcome, you'd have to create a new function. Better to print *outside* the function:

```
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

def divide(x, y):
    return x / y

x = 8
y = 4

print '%d + %d = %d' % (x, y, add(x, y))
print '%d - %d = %d' % (x, y, subtract(x, y))
print '%d * %d = %d' % (x, y, multiply(x, y))
print '%d / %d = %d' % (x, y, divide(x, y))
```

Answer (score 0):

You `return x + y` from inside your function `add`, so the value `x + y` is being sent to wherever you call it. However, at the *call site*, you simply have `add(x, y)`; you aren't "catching" it, so to speak. You could try:

```
result = add(x, y)
print(result)
```

or simply:

```
print(add(x, y))
```